# Including a model's virtual attributes when converting a record to JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I'm trying to convert an ActiveRecord model to JSON in Rails, and while the to_json method generally works, the model's virtual attributes are not included.  Is there a way within Rails to list not just the attributes of a model, but also it's attr_accessor and attr_reader attributes in order that all readable attributes are available when the model is converted to JSON?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before Rails 3, use the **:method** option:

```
@model.to_json(:method => %w(some_virtual_attribute another_virtual_attribute))
```

In Rails 3, use **:methods** option

```
@model.to_json(:methods => %w(some_virtual_attribute another_virtual_attribute))
```

Comment: This works for me but then I cant filter the attributes using `:only => [:attr1, :attr2]`. Is there a way to combine `:only` with the `:methods` parameter?

Comment: `to_json(only: [:key_a, :key_b], methods: [:method_name])`

Answer (score 15):

I did this to put the information in the model and to keep the method compatible with any way another class might call it (`as_json` is called by `to_json` and is supposed to return a `Hash`):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json options=nil
    options ||= {}
    options[:methods] = ((options[:methods] || []) + [:my, :virtual, :attrs])
    super options
  end
end
```

(tested in Rails v3.0)

Comment: +1: This worked nicely and I like the idea to define this once in my model class

Comment: I really liked this solution too, very elegant...indeed! The best part of this one is that it snapped into ActiveAdmin without any trouble, the controllers are abstract and dynamically generated so this was certainly the shortest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it changed in Rails 3 but now you have to use the :methods option instead of :method

Answer (score 0):

Other answers refer to the `methods` call which returns all methods, including those which aren't attributes. An alternative approach would be to use `attributes` which returns the model's attributes except that it doesn't include its virtual attributes.

If those are known, then adding something like the below to the model might help:

```
VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES = %i{foo bar baz}
VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES.each { |a| attr_accessor a } # create accessors
def attributes
  VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES.each_with_object(super) { |a,h| h[a] = self.send(a) }
end
```